# Why do I keep getting a "java.io.FileNotFoundException" error on my code?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I have been working for a few hours on trying to fix this code, and have visited countless questions on this site.

I apologize for the code dump, but I am not sure what is going wrong with the code.

The error is based in the reading of the file, but I included all my code to be safe.

```
package ch7;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;    
public class DistributionChart 
{   
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      int size = 10;
      int[] ranges = new int[size];  // each entry represents a range of values          
      getData(ranges);   //pass the entire array into the method          
      displayChart(ranges);          
      getDataFromFile(ranges);          
      displayChartToFile(ranges);          
      System.out.println("\nSee you later!!");          
   } //end of main       
   public static void getData(int[] someArray)
   {           
       Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);     
       System.out.println ("Enter a series of numbers between 1 and 100. Separate each number with a space.");
       System.out.println ("Signal the end by entering a number outside " +
             "of that range and then press enter.");
       System.out.print("Go: ");           
       //reads an arbitrary number of integers that are in the range 1 to 100 inclusive
       //for each integer read in, determine which range it is in and increment the corresponding element in the array         
       //your code goes here
          int values = 0;             
          values = scan.nextInt();            
          while(values > 0 && values < 101)
          {
              if(values >= 1 && values <= 10)
              {                   
                  someArray[0]++;
              }               
              else if (values >= 11 && values <= 20)
              {                   
                   someArray[1] ++;
              }
              else if (values >= 21 && values <= 30)
              {                   
                   someArray[2]++;
              }
              else if(values >= 31 && values <= 40)
              {                   
                  someArray[3]++;
              }               
              else if(values >= 41 && values <= 50)
              {
                  someArray[4]++;
              }               
              else if(values >= 51 && values <= 60)
              {
                someArray[5]++;                 
              }               
              else if(values >= 61 && values <= 70)
              {
                  someArray[6]++;
              }               
              else if(values >= 71 && values <= 80)
              {
                  someArray[7]++;
              }               
              else if(values >= 81 && values <= 90)
              {
                   someArray[8]++;
              }               
              else if(values >= 91 && values <= 100)
              {
                   someArray[9]++;
              }               
              values = scan.nextInt();                
          }         
        scan.close();  
   }//end of getData       
   public static void displayChart(int[] someArray)
   {
       System.out.println("Distribution chart by Royce T.");
       System.out.println("================================");   
       //Print histogram.
         for(int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++)
       {    
           System.out.print( ((i * 10 + 1)) + "-" + (((i *10 +1)) + 9) + " \t" + "|");             
           for(int y = 0; y < someArray[i]; y++)
           {
               System.out.print("*");
           }
              System.out.println();
          }

   } //end of displayChart    
   public static void getDataFromFile(int[] someArray) throws IOException
   {
       Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/RTmag/workspaceRATI//CSC110/inputFile.txt"));
       int values = 0;
       while(inFile.hasNext())
       {               
              values = inFile.nextInt();                  
              while(values > 0 && values < 101)
              {
                  if(values >= 1 && values <= 10)
                  {                       
                      someArray[0]++;
                  }                   
                  else if (values >= 11 && values <= 20)
                  {                       
                       someArray[1] ++;
                  }
                  else if (values >= 21 && values <= 30)
                  {                       
                       someArray[2]++;
                  }
                  else if(values >= 31 && values <= 40)
                  {                       
                      someArray[3]++;
                  }                   
                  else if(values >= 41 && values <= 50)
                  {
                      someArray[4]++;
                  }                   
                  else if(values >= 51 && values <= 60)
                  {
                    someArray[5]++;
                  }
                  else if(values >= 61 && values <= 70)
                  {
                      someArray[6]++;
                  }                   
                  else if(values >= 71 && values <= 80)
                  {
                      someArray[7]++;
                  }                   
                  else if(values >= 81 && values <= 90)
                  {
                       someArray[8]++;
                  }                   
                  else if(values >= 91 && values <= 100)
                  {
                       someArray[9]++;
                  }                   
                  values = inFile.nextInt();                      
              }             
            inFile.close();
       }
   }
       public static void displayChartToFile(int[] someArray) throws IOException
       {
           getDataFromFile(someArray);
           PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter( "C:/Users/RTmag/workspaceRATI//CSC110/outputFile.txt");        
           //Print chart title with your name
           outFile.println("Distribution chart by Royce T.");
           outFile.println("================================");
           //Print histogram.
           for(int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++)
           {    
               outFile.print( ((i * 10 + 1)) + "-" + (((i *10 +1)) + 9) + " \t" + "|");                
               for(int x = 0; x <someArray[i]; x++)
               {
                 outFile.print("*");
               }                   
               outFile.println();                  
           }
           outFile.close();  
       }
   }    
// end of DistributionChart tester class
```

I am attempting to have the displayChartToFile method write to a file named outputFile.txt that is located in the CSC110 folder. This folder also contains my bin and src folders.

Whenever I run my code, the first two methods properly display after I input.

example of output with errors:

```
Enter a series of numbers between 1 and 100. Separate each number with a space.
Signal the end by entering a number outside of that range and then press enter.
Go: 55 66 555
Distribution chart by Royce T.
================================
1-10    |
11-20   |
21-30   |
31-40   |
41-50   |
51-60   |*
61-70   |*
71-80   |
81-90   |
91-100  |
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\RTmag\workspaceRATI\CSC110\inputFile.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ch7.DistributionChart.getDataFromFile(DistributionChart.java:143)
    at ch7.DistributionChart.main(DistributionChart.java:28)
```

Line 28 is:

```
getDataFromFile(ranges);
```

Line 143 is :

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/RTmag/workspaceRATI//CSC110/inputFile.txt"));
```

The text inside inputFile.txt is

```
75 49 62 35 18 97 62 54 83 61 44 29 98 75 14
```

outputFile.txt is empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

And if I don't have all the information you may need to help me just let me know!

#### EDIT:

I fixed the file location, but now it is returning a new set of errors.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at ch7.DistributionChart.getDataFromFile(DistributionChart.java:207)
    at ch7.DistributionChart.main(DistributionChart.java:30)
```

Comment: Make sure that the file exists at the specified location ... also, not sure what the `//` is for

Comment: @MadProgrammer I removed the unnecessary slash before CSC110 and made sure the files were there. The code still gives the same errors.

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(new File("C:/Users/RTmag/workspaceRATI/CSC110/inputFile.txt").exists());` if this prints `false`, then the file is not where you think it is

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, so it returned false and I fixed that, but now it is returning a different error.

The new error is added in original post.

Comment: Okay, maybe you should consider closing/deleting this question (now it's solved) and post a new question with the new error and code

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would do that, but it won't let me ask a new question. Would it be frowned upon to keep up this post but use edits to try and solve the new error?

Comment: Yes, I would be considered a bad idea, as you're changing the question, the current answer is no longer applicable and could be downvoted as irrelevant

Comment: How many lines are you expecting there to be in the input file?

Comment: @MadProgrammer one line in the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this looks wrong...

```
int values = 0;
while (inFile.hasNext()) {

    values = inFile.nextInt();

    while (values > 0 && values < 101) {
        //...
        values = inFile.nextInt();
    }
}
```

- You check to see if the file has any more lines, good
- You get the next `int` value, good
- You loop while the values are between `1..100`, okay, but what happens if you reach the end of the input?
- You read the next `int` ... ah, not sure about that.

Given your input of `75 49 62 35 18 97 62 54 83 61 44 29 98 75 14` you could simply do something like...

```
int values = 0;
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    values = inFile.nextInt();
    //...
}
```

But if the input file might have multiple lines, you could do...

```
int values = 0;
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    String nextLine = inFile.nextLine();
    Scanner line = new Scanner(nextLine);
    while (line.hasNextInt()) {
        values = line.nextInt();
        //...
    }
}
```

(You could do this even if it had only one line).

The basic problem is, you're reading to the end of the file and `Scanner` has run out of data to read

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/RTmag/workspaceRATI//CSC110/inputFile.txt"));
```

to either

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/RTmag/workspaceRATI/CSC110/inputFile.txt"));
```

or

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\RTmag\\workspaceRATI\\CSC110\\inputFile.txt"));
```